# Preferred way to Iterate a Rust Vec?

Tags: rust

With following code, is `first_word2()` better than `first_word1()`, as it does not copy items?

```
fn first_word1(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}

fn first_word2(s: &String) -> usize {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if *item == b' ' {
            return i;
        }
    }

    s.len()
}
```

What about iterating a `Vec<String>`? Is `for (i, item) in` preferred than `for (i, &item) in`?

**EDIT**:

Here is version for `Vec<String>`:

```
fn find_space1(v: &Vec<String>) -> usize {
    for (i, &item) in v.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == " " {
            return i;
        }
    }
    v.len()
}

fn find_space2(v: &Vec<String>) -> usize {
    for (i, item) in v.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == " " {
            return i;
        }
    }
    v.len()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your code snippets are semantically equivalent. It does not matter if you:

- destructure the reference via `(i, &item)` and then use `item` directly, or
- dereference `item` like `*item` for each usage.

They will compile down to the same machine code, so there is no difference in speed or anything. The only reason to prefer one over the other is: how much you have to type. For example, if your condition would be `item == b' ' || item == b'_'`, then I would say the destructuring `(i, &item)` solution is better since you only need one `&` as opposed to two `*`.

> If the preferred solution for a `Vec<u8>` is `(i, item)` (rather than `(i, &item)`), what about iterating a `Vec<String>`?

You can't use either version with `String`, as it does not implement `Copy`. But you also don't need to copy/clone it in order to compare it. `s == " "` works fine when `s` is a `&String`.

---

Independent of your question, you can improve your code in another way: by using iterator chains.

```rust
fn first_space(s: &String) -> usize {
    s.bytes().position(|b| b == b' ').unwrap_or(s.len())
}
```

Improvements:

- `String::bytes` is an easier way to iterate over the bytes of a string
- `Iterator::position` already implements the logic your `for` loop is implementing
- `unwrap_or` is ideal to provide a fallback

Comment: Thank you. I think the second version (`find_space2()`) can be used in `Vec<String>`, see my edited code snippet.

Comment: @mitnk Well, you second version for `Vec<String>` does not include the dereference operation `*item`. So it's different from the second version of `Vec<u8>`. But yes, it works.

Comment: For `Vec<String>`, the `for (i, &item) in` version does not work because of `String` not having `Copy` implemented. Does that mean `for (i, item) in` version IS a better version, version not copying items?